# Docker .net core 3.0 preview 3 (web api + angular) on os X

Tags: macos, docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to dockerize a .net core 3.0 (preview 3) web api + angular application on osx.

I have the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:3.0-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM microsoft/dotnet:3.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./HelloWorldApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "HelloWorldApp.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "HelloWorldApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HelloWorldApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWorldApp.dll"]
```

When building the image, I have the following error message

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

NB) The application compiles and run if not using docker.

(sorry my english is not good)

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks 
Claude

Comment: Can you run it without docker as a standalone project? To me this sounds like a compilor error, have you installed the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` nuget package?

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting is not referenced in the .csproj file. But yes it compiles and run as a standalone project. I have tried to add the package but it changes nothing. Same behavior : it works as standalone and the same compilation error when building a docker image.

Comment: I have the same problem. After adding 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting' package the errors remain.

Comment: Have you used `IWebHostEnvironment` in your project? I made a test with built-in template in Docker for windows, it works correctly, could you verfiy whether this issue exist in windows environemnt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating your `Dockerfile` to the following should work

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./HelloWorldApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "HelloWorldApp.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "HelloWorldApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HelloWorldApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWorldApp.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks with your help, the process has gone one step further. But it fails later because the project contains an angular part and "npm install" can't run in the container. I'm now trying to use the following solution http://alakbarv.azurewebsites.net/2019/01/11/dockerize-asp-net-core-angular-application-solving-error-the-command-npm-install-exited-with-code-127/   to separe the dotnet build and the angular comilation.

Comment: @AndyL Is there a place to reference what switching to the different image provider does that isn't included in the default?